# second-order divided differenc

Tags: calculus, recurrence-relations

Let's have the periodic function

$f(t_0)=−5$

$f(t_1)=−10$

$f(t_2)=−5$

where $t_0$, $t_1$ and $t_2$ are equally spaced. All I need to know is the sign of the sum

$\sum\limits_{i=0}^{i=2} {f(t_i)f′(t_i)}$

Obviously, however, the above function is not differentiable and therefore $f′(t_i)$ cannot be determined. Can I substitute the above sum by the product of the average function value for the period and its second-order divided difference and thus make a conclusion about the sign of that sum -- say, in the case at hand claim that it's negative?

Comment: You must interpolate the periodic function $f(t_n)$ first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we can assume that $f'(t_0)<0$, $f'(t_1)=0$ and $f'(t_2) = -f'(t_0)$.

Then  $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{i=2} {f(t_i)f′(t_i)} = 0$

Comment: Under that assumprion, said sum (with $i$ running from 0 to 4) will be negative for a function having the values -5, 0, -5, -10, -5, right? Is the assumption acceptable, though?

Comment: I thought in this way: $i_1$  is max (where f(i_1)=0) => $f'(i_1)=0$, in point $i_0$ function increase so $f'(i_0)>0$  and so on.

Comment: This seems to me to be the case as well but I'd like to hear objections, if a all, from other mathematicians. If there are none, I'll accept the answer.

Comment: @nikiat2 You certainly can *not* make that assumption unless you have further information about $f$. Samples of $f$ at finitely many points say *nothing* about the possible values of $f'$.

Comment: @fgp Ok, in this case we can not say anything about the sum.

Answer (score 1):

In fact $f(t_n)$ is not difficult to interpolate, just $f(t_n)=\dfrac{5\cos\pi n-15}{2}$

Then $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{2}f(t_i)f′(t_i)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{2}\dfrac{5\cos\pi i-15}{2}\left(-\dfrac{5\pi\sin\pi i}{2}\right)=0$

Comment: Thanks a lot, doraemonpaul. This is similar to @nikita2's suggestion, isn't it? By the same token $\sum\limits_{i = 0}^{i = 4} {\left(5 sin \left( i \frac{\pi}{2} \right) - 10 \right) \left(5 cos \left( i \frac{\pi}{2} \right)  \right)} < 0$ which shows that treating $f'(t)$ in terms of $\delta$-functions is incorrect since it yields 0. Do you agree with that?

Comment: What reason is there to pick this particular interpolation, and not any other of the gazillion possible interpolations? You might just as well pick a desired value for the sum in question, and then construct an interpolation which produces it...